# DBeaver does not refresh table informations about constraints

Tags: dbeaver

1. In navigator, I press F4 on some table to see constraints of that table. I close the table window.
2. Outside DBeaver I delete some not null constraint of that table.
3. Coming back to DBeaver I press F4 again to see again the constraints of the table and the deleted constraint is still there.

Am I missing something? Bug?

DBeaver 21.0.4, Oracle database & driver